# TypeScript make both arguments of a function match their type argument

Tags: typescript

I'm not sure how to make a descriptive title for this particular question, sorry for that.

In Angular (this question can be answered by only knowing TypeScript), I have created several utility functions to ensure that when we setup providers, the correct types are used. So I create a **createValueProvider**, **createClassProvider** and **createFactoryProvider**, they basically ensure that the first argument (the token / Type, aka **provide property**) and the second argument (useValue / useClass / useFactory) has matching types.

Example for **createValueProvider**, which works:

```js
type TokenValue<Token> = Token extends InjectionToken<infer V> ? V : never;
type TypeValue<Type> = Type extends new (...args: unknown[]) => infer R ? R : never;

export const createValueProvider = <Token extends InjectionToken<any> | Type<any>>(provide: Token, useValue: TokenValue<Token> | TypeValue<Token>): ValueProvider => {
    return {
        provide,
        useValue,
    };
};

const MY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('My string');
createValueProvider(MY_TOKEN, 'Test'); // OK
createValueProvider(MY_TOKEN, 123); // Error: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

interface Base {
    prop: string;
}
class BaseImpl implements Base {
    prop = '';
}

createValueProvider(BaseImpl, { prop: '' }); // OK
createValueProvider(BaseImpl, { prop: 123 }); // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

So the above code validates that given a token or type as first argument, the second has to be a value of the type argument of whatever is provided as the first argument.

I can't make it work with the following function **createExistingProvider**, for which the second argument as to be of a similar type as the first. It's easier to explain with code. Let's simplify the problem with just InjectionToken and ignore Type:

```js
export const createExistingProvider = <Token extends InjectionToken<any>>(
    provide: Token,
    useExisting: Token extends InjectionToken<infer Value> ? InjectionToken<Value> : never
): Provider => {
    return {
        provide,
        useExisting,
    };
};

const EXISTING_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('Existing');
const NEW_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<number>('New');
const SECOND_NEW_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('Second New');

createExistingProvider(NEW_TOKEN, EXISTING_TOKEN); // Should fail, but doesn't (one is InjectionToken<number> and other InjectionToken<string>)
createExistingProvider(SECOND_NEW_TOKEN, EXISTING_TOKEN); // OK (both InjectionToken<string>)
```

Is there a way to make the above code throw me a compilation error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure ```Token extends InjectionToken<infer Value>``` returns a boolean, maybe you can try ```Token instanceOf InjectionToken<infer Value> ? ... : ...```

Comment: It does return a boolean and instanceOf is not valid in TypeScript's typing context (neither is instanceof). Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be possible since the generic parameter of the injection token is only used in the constructor(And in another place, but that method is marked internal). So the resulting type from any version of [`InjectionToken`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/di/injection_token.ts) becomes the same type to typescript.

I try to demonstrate how the existence of a generic field changes how typescript behaves in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=63&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1AlgFwBYHsCuGAYmhADYAmSA3gFBL1LykhRRICSwAVhPBmjmAAVHAGsIwADxCAfNToNF8QVAwAnPHxxqAFOWjwAXElVq0wAOYBKagF8F9ew6QYAnjGQBRAB5pV5iwAFNRwANyQAXmoYENC0fWMQYFcAGiQ8KAgfP35LROSnRTcPDmAAMwg1Th4+CHJpJAhvDAlyNmrefkERcSkk1xk5KKFG5tb27k6BYTEJSXMKtSQhDtryOQB+ZdWWymNgCFDKmmcmmG0MRhVL+DUIEBbs-0tgsPjKyKQGppbgNtKal0Zr1JP1BjpnIoYm8EssUpCGBksr5nhZjDtpj05pxFjs6tJBs4rMYnrkgrFInJaIpFHcMHg1MB5DSWUhoXF9PDWTSkaSAlzWbYANzOYUnZzKYCqJCeAAa7AAyisAHIAcQA+kIAPIAaU8ys+BwA7gCpt1ZlJTAEZDoAOR8yy2qwipTXJDKzwoTW6-WGiAmjHmkHAPBgABGlRttuV-qdLoYkulCs8AGEtcqACLqj1e7V6g1RY2mviYi2SK2WKMK3iCSgxo1xk5KO4PZE5AKvDmVHQ5735tJyxUqjV5-XOiUtx4osmd966ZNpzPZz19-UD+VK9hq1fK8fOYrIITQS5RQPAuYVixyH7jYtArFSEPhyNILbqPDIYxlECkTLOAD0-4MAAehsNBOKAkCwAgyDoNgxBkJQ1IJswrB3qWIKyMyrKhD+GzGEICL0Im75aLo+hQEYJjqAENhUPYiiFAwB4ytOHYUlEVDsu8+SpOkmQOmiSD9Ex9AsTilR4vUIw3n8EyAhhcxgkMyyjL8-xng+8zlB8KyTGsmzbPpuxIPshzHKc3jnGoNxurc9xTu2LyxHOnzfGMcnoUGSnJOCRFsi5sJCAKLK8mxeReeeUgSVUxn4rIMhEiS4XkmElLYSydIMkyyHcvQ3Gcv5ihhU5FghTSYqMSKTYJm6g6btuo4FkgRaaWWl5RoJjaulKly9k1foBsZimPqGEZqFG9bdbVvVIAu6ZZv1PrNa1w3eZaNGVna1aSnWsZ7s2Dltqis76LoS39jKG7Dju46Ha2gmnd281Lhda5XUOW4jstd0MPu7iHsenxtSCHVqbeINzE+42Ge+n5IN+v4QABQH0KB4E0EAA).

Disclaimer: I am not sure if I am correct, but it seems like it.

Comment: I see what you mean. It seems to me like you are correct. It actually make sense.

InjectionToken<number> and InjectionToken<string> both have the exact same types for their properties, so in the eyes of the compiler, they are the same.

So unless I use my own InjectionToken that extends the base Angular one, and somehow make their generic type alter their visible properties, I will not be able to achieve my goal. But it does not make sense to me to create a child class just for that...

Thanks for your time!